# What happens when JITter encounters another method call inside method's definition?

Tags: c#, runtime, clr, jit

Please consider the following situation. 
As you know before Main() executes CLR allocates an inner data structure for every referenced type inside Main(), which contains an entry for each method defined in the referenced type. Subsequently each entry holds reference (stub) to the block of memory where respective native code is stored.
Let's suppose while executing code inside Main() JITter encounters a method **SomeClass1.M1()**. SomeClass1 is referenced to find related IL code.
So here're the questions:

- what happens when CLR bumps into another method call inside M1(), let's say **SomeClass2.M2()**. Does it mean the second data structure containing methods of SomeClass2 is created and the address of the native code will then be bound to the corresponding method? If yes, then:

 - what will be stored inside the first data structure?
- what will be stored inside the first data structure if M1()'s description immediately starts with calling M2() and there's also some code inside M1() that follows M2().

Unfortunately all I've found on the web was a description saying that method's IL code is just compiled into native code and then gets executed.

So if my assumptions are not correct, please offer your opinion. 

Thank you!

Comment: This question will be hard to answer as it stands. You may want to look at the JIT [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/tree/master/src/jit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having carried out some additional research, I bumped into a detailed description provided in "Essential .NET: The Common Language Runtime". 
Initially every type initialized in the program is represented by a data structure, consisting of a method table. Each entry of the table is initialized with a call to a JITter procedure (JITter).

So invoking SomeClass1.M1() means that control is passed to the JITter procedure (through JMP instruction) which compiles respective IL code into a machine code. If there're some other submethods within M1() (like SomeClass2.M2() ) they will be referenced from inside the machine code through "call" instruction (each call instruction will reference respective method entry in the method table mentioned earlier). 

Having compiled the IL code JITter returns address of where the native instructions are stored to the respective entry of the method table. 

After that there goes execution of a just compiled piece of code and as soon as CLR encounters a submethod call it will reference the respective entry of the method table to see if it holds native instuctions' address or a JITer invocation. If it's the latter, JITter is invoked again otherwise JMP instuction (with address reference) is used to execute the block of native code.